# Spring boot csrf use

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I just want to use CSRF token with some url which are used for direct access.

And I don't want to use CSRF for that url which are basically REST apis for other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly use this code for a particular type of request which need to be served with out CSRF.

```
http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/rest/v1/**");
```

here /rest/v1/** will allow you to server all the request coming on the url starts with "rest/v1/".

Answer (score 2):

I find that the easiest way is to create an array of String with patterns, like this:

```
String [] publicUrls = new String [] {
            "/public/**",
            "/login",
            "/logout"
    };
```

Here is the code I use in CSRF. And the code for ignore URLs is this **.ignoringAntMatchers(publicUrls):**

```
http.csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .ignoringAntMatchers(publicUrls)
```

[Spring official doc ref](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/CsrfConfigurer.html#ignoringAntMatchers-java.lang.String...-)